# Что означают цифры в строке формата?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Что означают в строке `printf("%4.0f %6.1f\n", fahr,cels);` цифры 4.0 и 6.1?

```
using namespace System;

#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int lower, upper, step;
    float fahr, cels;
    lower = 0;
    upper = 300;
    step = 20;
    fahr = lower;
    while (fahr <= upper) {
        cels = (5.0 / 9.0) * (fahr - 32.0);
        printf("%4.0f %6.1f\n", fahr, cels);
        fahr = fahr + step;
    }
    _getch();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Фаренгейт печатать не более 4 цифр без дробной части. Цельсий - 6 цифр и 1 после точки